# Collision with Terrain/how to know the coordinates (x-y-z) of each point

Tags: xna, coordinates, collision, terrain

I have a 3D model which will collide with the terrain. How can I get the terrain  position coordinates?

Comment: We would need information on how (in code) your terrain represented. Maybe showing pertinent bits of your code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 3D terrain, the best way to go is heightmaps.
Since your terrain is generated from a texture files (pixels), it is easy to get the coordinate and height of each points.

Take a look at http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_basics.php